# How to apply coupon on specific brands in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

In magento1 I want to create a Coupon & apply that coupon when only specific brand product is added to cart, if any other brand product is applied then the coupon code should be automatically removed or should not apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new product attribute as a brand and assign value to products using mass action. After that Make sure you set value Yes in the dropdown "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" for the brand attribute.

Now you can able to see the brand attribute option in the action section while you creating a new promo code.

Make sure you do Reindexing and cache clear.
[image]

Below Is the condition as per your requirement. In place of SKU, you have to select the Brand attribute. 
[image]

Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: i have already done that, my issue is how to apply coupon code if any of the 5 brands products are in the cart alone or any of them but among 5 of them. If out of 5 any 6th brand products is added then remove the applied code

Comment: @Arjun Please check the updated answer

Comment: @Arjun any update is this working or not?

Comment: No working, I did it via custom code by override Flaterate.php & Freeshipping.php